# Alternative to for loops for calculating 15^6 combinations in Python

Tags: python, performance

Today, I have a nested for loop in python to calculate the value of all different combinations in a horse racing card consisting of six different races; i.e. six different arrays (of different lengths, but up to 15 items per array). It can be up to 11 390 625 combinations (15^6).

For each horse in each race, I calculate a value (EV) which I want to multiply.

Array 1: 1A,1B,1C,1D,1E,1F
Array 2: 2A,2B,2C,2D,2E,2F
Array 3: 3A,3B,3C,3D,3E,3F
Array 4: 4A,4B,4C,4D,4E,4F
Array 5: 5A,5B,5C,5D,5E,5F
Array 6: 6A,6B,6C,6D,6E,6F

1A * 1B * 1C * 1D * 1E * 1F = X,XX
.... .... .... .... ... ...
6A * 6B * 6C * 6D * 6E * 6F 0 X,XX

Doing four levels is OK. It takes me about 3 minutes.
I have yet not been able to do six levels.

I need help in creating a better way of doing this, and have no idea how to proceed. Does numpy perhaps offer help here? Pandas? I've tried compiling the code with Cython, but it did not help much.

My function takes in a list containing the horses in numerical order and their EV. (Since horse starting numbers do not start with zero, I add 1 to the index). I iterate through all the different races, and save the output for the combination into a dataframe.

```py
    def calculateCombos(horses_in_race_1,horses_in_race_2,horses_in_race_3,horses_in_race_4,horses_in_race_5,horses_in_race_6,totalCombinations, df):
        totalCombinations = 0
        for idx1, hr1_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_1):
            hr1_no = idx1 + 1
            for idx2, hr2_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_2):
                hr2_no = idx2 + 1
                for idx3, hr3_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_3):
                    hr3_no_ = idx3 + 1
                    for idx4, hr4_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_4):
                        hr4_no = idx4 + 1
                        for idx5, hr5_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_5):
                            hr5_no = idx5 + 1
                            for idx6, hr6_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_6):
                                hr6_no = idx6 + 1
                                totalCombinations = totalCombinations + 1
                                combinationEV = hr1_ev * hr2_ev * hr3_ev * hr4_ev * hr5_ev * hr6_ev
                                new_row = {'Race1':str(hr1_no),'Race2':str(hr2_no),'Race3':str(hr3_no),'Race4':str(hr4_no),'Race5':str(hr5_no),'Race6':str(hr6_no), 'EV':combinationEV}
                                df = appendCombinationToDF(df, new_row)
        return df
```

Comment: Can you please provide minimal, reproducible examples of your attempts? It will be much easier to help if you provide concrete code.

Comment: A direct search for "Python combinations" will lead you to the `itertools` package.

Comment: @prune Thank you! I am a newbie and I've tried to look at it, but looking at their examples, I have not been able to translate it into by problem.

Comment: Hi, I don't know if there is a way to make your brute-force-like calculation any easier, but you can make it at least a bit less costly by introducing level-wise temp variables that hold the result of the multiplication up until this level. Like `mul1 = hr1_ev` and `mul2 = mul1 * hr2_ev` and in the most inner loop `combinationEV = mul5 * hr6_ev`. This way you don't force the CPU to calculate the same values over and over again. Regards ... P.S.: Why exactly do you need all results? What are you really looking for?

Comment: Your inputs and outputs are not yet clear for the combinatoric process.  Please specify and give one or two concrete examples.

Comment: You can actually change the enumeration starting number. Here, enumeration starts from number 1. list(enumerate([1,2,3], start = 1)) --> [(1, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you try this and see if you can run the function without any issues? This works on my laptop (I'm using PyCharm). If you can't run this, then I would say that you need a better PC perhaps. I did not encounter any memory error.

Assume that we have the following:

```
horses_in_race_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
horses_in_race_2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
horses_in_race_3 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
horses_in_race_4 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
horses_in_race_5 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
horses_in_race_6 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15]
```

I have re-written the function as follows - made a change in enumeration. Also, not using df as I do not know what function this is - `appendCombinationToDF`

```
def calculateCombos(horses_in_race_1,horses_in_race_2,horses_in_race_3,horses_in_race_4,horses_in_race_5,horses_in_race_6):
    for idx1, hr1_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_1, start = 1):
        for idx2, hr2_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_2, start = 1):
            for idx3, hr3_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_3, start = 1):
                for idx4, hr4_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_4, start = 1):
                    for idx5, hr5_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_5, start = 1):
                        for idx6, hr6_ev in enumerate(horses_in_race_6, start = 1):
                            combinationEV = hr1_ev * hr2_ev * hr3_ev * hr4_ev * hr5_ev * hr6_ev
                            new_row = {'Race1':str(idx1),'Race2':str(idx2),'Race3':str(idx3),'Race4':str(idx4),'Race5':str(idx5),'Race6':str(idx6), 'EV':combinationEV}
                            l.append(new_row)
                            #df = appendCombinationToDF(df, new_row)
l = [] # df = ...
calculateCombos(horses_in_race_1, horses_in_race_2, horses_in_race_3, horses_in_race_4, horses_in_race_5, horses_in_race_6)
```

Executing `len(l)`, I get:

```
11390625 # maximum combinations possible. This means that above function ran successfully and computation succeeded.
```

If the above can be executed, replace list `l` with `df` and see if function can execute without encountering memory error. I was able to run the above in less than 20-30 seconds.